# When building a report in BI SAP, how do I create a dynamic Task Finish Date filter that will change with each monthly report?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Specifically, if the report is scheduled for the 31st of every month, at 11:59 PM, I want the report to show data from that month.

Example: Report is run on Jan 31, 2016 11:59 PM. I would like the data to show everything with Task Finish Date from Jan 1, 2016 - Jan 31, 2016.

Thanks!

Comment: I've decided to make it easier by running the report at the end of the month I will need data from, at 11:59PM. I will then set two variables: FirstDayOfMonth and LastDayOfMonth, and will filter against these. I have LastDayOfMonth built, because LastDayOfMonth() is a built in function. However, can't figure out how to grab the first day of that month. Ideas?

Comment: Please move the content from your comment to your original question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to create variable which will return for specified dates in cross table zero or one. Then set filter on it and show only 'ones'. 

the solution you've provided is also simple - fistdayofmonth might be created by creating new date as year(run_date)+monthnumber(run_date)+"01"